# Resume file transfers between 2 Windows PCs, no ftp

Tags: windows, internet, ftp, file-transfer

I'm looking for an alternative to FTP for transferring big files between 2 windows PCs.

In this case;

- The local PC is windows 7
- The remote PC is windows 2003 SBS

Due to some problems can't install MS FTP this time. I can install a free FTP server, but I'm looking for an alternative to FTP, so I can use it for different machines.

I think it's not possible with the free LogMeIn. But I'm not sure if resumable file transfer is possible with the free TeamViewer (if it is, then great! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install sshd and rsync, then you can use rsync from the other machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it's an even heavier solution than FTP (especially for non-server cases), it also needs to store sync data. However this is a valid answer for the question, I'm marking it as the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[Microsoft Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx) is built in to Windows, and works somewhat similarly to rsync. It has support for resuming interrupted file transfers, and can also choose which files to copy based on which files have been updated and other criteria. This solution would prevent you from needing to use any third-party tools. You would need to be able to map a network drive between the two computers though, so if it's across the internet, you would need to forward the appropriate ports or use some sort of SSH or VPN solution.

Answer (score 1):

Tried Teamviewer, it supports resume for downloads, doesn't need any installation / admin rights, doesn't need NAT mapping, and is free for non-commercial use.